# Installing unidecode python module

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation

I installed python module unidecode: downloaded it, run setup.py. Exactly as I did for any other python module.

Then tried `import unidecode`: It works only in the downloaded directory. What's wrong?

Comment: Where has it installed to? Is the parent directory in your PYTHONPATH? It should normally install to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ `. You can check the path by opening a Python interactive window, typing `import sys` `print sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

just run setup.py with the wrong python version. Solved.